# Prove that $\{z\in \mathbb{C}, |z|=1\}\cong\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

How to prove that $T=\{z\in \mathbb{C}, |z|=1\}$, $T\cong\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: Find a homomorphism $(\Bbb R,+,0)\to (T,*,1)$ such that the kernel is exactly $\Bbb Z$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be given by $\phi(t) = e^{2 \pi i t}$.

Suppose $\phi(s)=\phi(t)$, what does that say about the relationship between $s$ and $t$?

Comment: Ok, I picked up the idea. $Im(\phi)=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Ker(\phi)}$. Thank you.

Comment: For the ideas of homomorphism and isomorphism to have meaning, we need to know the algebraic structures. It might be worth mentioning, for example, the operations.

Comment: My approach would be to get the idea straight first, then worry about the legalities...

Answer (score 1):

$f:(\mathbb{R},+)\to (S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1,.\}$ given by $f(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$

$f(x+y)=e^{2\pi i(x+y)}=e^{2\pi ix}.e^{2\pi i y}=f(x).f(y)$

shows that this map is a homomorphism , kernel is $\mathbb{Z}$

so $(\mathbb{R},+)/\mathbb{Z}\cong S^1$

Comment: To know the kernel, one needs to know the group structure of the image. It might be worth mentioning the operations.

Comment: @FlybyNight You are so kind, Thank You.

Comment: I edited the post by habit and then undid it. Perhaps use \times or \cdot for multiplication to get $\times$ or $\cdot$.